# Impossible to migrate the "System.Directory.Services.Protocols" dll from version "4.0.0" to "5.0.1" with nuget (.net framework 4.8)

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I have a project that uses the "System.Directory.Services.Protocols" dll which is in version `4.0` and references the framework:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll.
```

I want to update the dll because there is a [security hole in 5.0.0 fixed in 5.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.Protocols/#versions-tab).

But when I update with nuget (after removing the reference from my project), everything goes correctly (I don't get any error) but the referenced dll is still the one from framework `4.8`.

I tried to reference it manually by adding it from the "net-standard 2.0" package directory

```
Packages\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.5.0.1\lib
    | net45\ <empty>
    | netstandard2.0\System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.dll
```

but it doesn't work any better.

I thought the `4.8` [framework was compatible with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) `.net standard 2.0`, so why doesn't it select this dll?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue with fx4.8 and System.Directory.Services.Protocols nuget package version 6.0.1.
I think the problem is the incorrect package.
Try to bind version using app.config, for example:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.1" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```